# Rotate a text MeshResource so it won't be mirrored

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

When adding a text MeshResource, with no angle and with a fixed world position, it looks fine from the camera perspective.
However, when the user walks to the other side of the text entity and turns around, it looks mirrored.

I don't want to use the look(at_) API since I only want to rotate it around the Y-axis 180 degrees and when the user passes it again to reset the angle to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we have to put text in anchor that will stay in the same orientation even when we rotate text. Then add `textIsMirrored` variable that will handle rotation when changed:

```
class TextAnchor: Entity,HasAnchoring {
        let textEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateText("text"))
        var textIsMirrored = false {
            willSet {
                if newValue != textIsMirrored {
                    if newValue == true {
                        textEntity.setOrientation(.init(angle: .pi, axis: [0,1,0]), relativeTo: self)
                    } else {
                        textEntity.setOrientation(.init(angle: 0, axis: [0,1,0]), relativeTo: self)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        required init() {
            super.init()
            textEntity.scale = [0.01,0.01,0.01]
            anchoring = AnchoringComponent(.plane(.horizontal, classification: .any, minimumBounds: [0.3,0.3]))
            addChild(textEntity)
        }
}
```

Then in your `ViewController` you can create anchor that will have Camera as a target so we can track camera position and create out `textAnchor`:

```
let cameraAnchor = AnchorEntity(.camera)
let textAnchor = TextAnchor()
```

For it to work you have to add it as a child of your scene (preferably in `viewDidLoad`):

```
arView.scene.addAnchor(cameraAnchor)
arView.scene.addAnchor(textAnchor)
```

Now in ARSessionDelegate function you can check camera position in relation to your text and rotate it if Z axis is below 0:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
    if cameraAnchor.position(relativeTo: textAnchor).z < 0 {
        textAnchor.textIsMirrored = true
    } else {
        textAnchor.textIsMirrored = false
    }
}
```